# How to create template for this function?

Tags: c++, templates

For structs

```
<template typename T>
struct Foo
{
 ...
}

<template typename T>
struct Boo
{
 ...
}
```

I want to create function that i will call like

```
DoSomething<Boo<int>>(x);
DoSomething<Foo<float>>(x);
```

I tried something like this

```
<template typename T>
<template typename U>
void DoSomething(T<U>& x)
```

but it doesn't compile. How do I make template for this kind of function?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use template template parameter if you want to specify both types:

```
template <template<typename> class T, typename U>
void DoSomething(T<U>& x)
```

But depending on what you want to achieve, if you don't need to have both types in your function, simply using a single template parameter should work:

```
template <typename Y>
void DoSomething(T& x)
```

Comment: I need first one because I'm calling HelperFunction<U>(a,b) inside DoSomething function. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4):

just do:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{ 
};

template <typename T>
struct Boo
{ 
};

template <typename T>
void DoSomething(T& x)  // One parameter is enough, compiler will deduce types automatically
{
}    

Boo<int> x;
Foo<float> y;

DoSomething(x);   // compiler will generate void DoSomething(Boo<int>& x) 
DoSomething(y);   // compiler will generate void DoSomething(Foo<float>& x)
```

Your template declaration is wrong,

```
<template typename T> // invalid syntax
```

should be:

```
template <typename T>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<template typename T>
void DoSomething(T& x)
{
// do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices. For the sake of the examples, consider your `Foo` template struct and this declaration:

```
Foo<double> v;
```

Your first choice is

```
template <typename T>
void DoSomething1(T& x) { /* ... */ }
// ...
DoSomething1(v);
```

I strongly believe this is what you need.

However, it might not be the case. Perhaps, you really need to call the function on a type of the form `T<U>` where `T` is a template class and `U` is a type. For instance you might want to instantiate `T` with an `int` (that is, create `T<int> y;`) inside the function's body. Then, your second choice is

```
template <template <typename> class T, typename U>
void DoSomething2(T<U>& x) { T<int> y; /* ... */ }
// ...
DoSomething2(v);
```

Unfortunately, this might not yet be enough! If you try,

```
std::vector<double> w;
// ...
DoSomething2(w);
```

The last line fails to compile. The reason is that `std::vector` is a template class that take two type parameters and `DoSomething2` expects a template class that takes just one. (Of course one can instantiate `std::vector` with just one argument because the second one has a default value.) The solution is using a C++11 variadic template template parameter:

```
template <template <typename, typename...> class T, typename U>
void DoSomething3(T<U>&) { T<int> y; /* ... */ }
// ...
DoSomething3(v);
DoSomething3(w);
```